# Better way to use smart contracts on the developers' side?

Tags: javascript, solidity

I recently started exploring the crypto world and experimenting with smart contracts. I am writing a frontend app to interact with the uniswap contracts. I found out that to interact with smart contracts you need to include the ABI JSON file, which is kind of strange as we usually import JSON files only for config purposes. And the interaction with the contract is not really smooth at all, at lea for the developer. The included ABI does not really construct a local model or class of the contract. So for example to get the data from a unisawp pool, I had to  do:

```
    async function getPoolImmutables(poolContract: ethers.Contract) {
    const [factory, token0, token1, fee, tickSpacing, maxLiquidityPerTick] = await Promise.all([
        poolContract.factory(),
        poolContract.token0(),
        poolContract.token1(),
        poolContract.fee(),
        poolContract.tickSpacing(),
        poolContract.maxLiquidityPerTick(),
    ])
    const immutables: Immutables = {
        factory,
        token0,
        token1,
        fee,
        tickSpacing,
        maxLiquidityPerTick,
    }
    return immutables
}
    async function getPoolState(poolContract: ethers.Contract) {
        const [liquidity, slot] = await Promise.all([poolContract.liquidity(), poolContract.slot0()])
        const PoolState: State = {
            liquidity,
            sqrtPriceX96: slot[0],
            tick: slot[1],
            observationIndex: slot[2],
            observationCardinality: slot[3],
            observationCardinalityNext: slot[4],
            feeProtocol: slot[5],
            unlocked: slot[6],
        }
        return PoolState
    }
    async function getPool(poolData): Promise<Pool> {
    try {
        const poolAddress = poolData.id;
        // Get contract and data
        const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(poolAddress, IUniswapV3PoolABI, provider)
        const [immutables, state] = await Promise.all([getPoolImmutables(poolContract), getPoolState(poolContract)]);
        // Set up tokens
        const TokenA = new Token(chainId, immutables.token0, parseInt(poolData.token0.decimals), poolData.token0.symbol)
        const TokenB = new Token(chainId, immutables.token1, parseInt(poolData.token1.decimals), poolData.token1.symbol)

        // Check if enough liquidity
        const liqString = state.liquidity.toString();
        if (liqString.length < 20) {
            return undefined;
        }
        // Create and return pool
        const pool = new Pool(
            TokenA,
            TokenB,
            immutables.fee,
            state.sqrtPriceX96.toString(),
            state.liquidity.toString(),
            state.tick
        )
        return pool;
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If the JS interface were in the development environment, this should be something as simple as:

```
async function getPool(address): Pool {
    const pool = new Pool(address);
    return await pool.get();
}
```

The returned object from the above function would have all the data populated and all the methods of the contract. This should be easy as the solidity interface of the contracts is publicly available. If you had the actual interface in your env you would not re-construct the data model.

The app-developer side does not seem so friendly yet. I've been watching some youtube vids of people explaining smart contract interaction and they keep going back and forth between their code and the solidity contract.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

The ABI is used to represent the interface of the smart contract you want to interact with. Its a JSON because you can interact with smart contracts from different languages, so having a JS interface or model would limit the use of Solidity to JS.

The ABI is mainly used by other libraries that work as a middle man between the developer and the blockchain ecosystem, such as web3js or etherjs. These libraries take on the ABI JSON and return an object with the methods and properties of the contract, making it fairly simple to interact with it.

If you are new to web3 and want to develop on Solidity with Ethereum, I heavily recommend you to do the tracks at https://learnweb3.io/.